# DataBaseHelper, Singleton or not?

Tags: android, ormlite

There have been a few questions on this topic but none giving firm reasons for why there should or shouldn't be a single or multiple instances of the databaseHelper.
When is it a good idea to have multiple instances of DatabaseHelper and when is it not.  Is less complexity  (if that is actually the case ) a good enough reason to have just a single instance ?

Comment: probably security is the first reason :)

Comment: are you saying a single instance is more secure?

Comment: definitely you have to always make sure when you open a connection, complete the process and close it right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `DatabaseHelper` should be a singleton for sure.  Each helper maintains the single connection to the database.   If you have multiple helpers with connections to the same database, then concurrency issues will result.  Sqlite does it's own locking underneath the single connection to ensure proper concurrent access to the database so using that single connection (and therefore that single helper) for all of your database operations is recommended and required.

Comment: I read in a good few threads ( Indeed Kevins edit in this thread ) about closing a connection after using it. As I'm using ORMlite and getting my DAO from the DBhelper class,  do I need to worry about closing connections ?   When I call the following     entity = getDao().queryForId(id);   do I need to worry about connections being left open or will ORMlite look after this?

Comment: @user965895 You should not need to close the connection.  The Android OS will take care of that when it unloads your application.

Comment: So as long as we use `OpenHelperManager` to get a reference then we should be good, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use one DatabaseHelper for each database in the application.  SQLite takes care of file locking for you (many reads, only one write) and Android using Java locking in SQLiteDatabase.  However, you can still get have a concurrency failure (simulataneous connections writing at once).  It's the multiple connnections part that you want to avoid and that is what is managed by one instance of the DatabaseHelper.

Comment: Just curious how you think your answer improved on mine 20 minutes previous?

Comment: I was drafting my answer while you submitted yours... just a timing thing.