# Duplicate value in SQLite Database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use SQLite in my Android App.
I take a CSV file, read this, and I write a record in internal DB.
No problem. But when I read value, at the first run, the number of value is correct, if I close and reopen the app, I found double value or triple value.

In my query, I'm using `'CREATE IF NOT EXISTS'` but the result is the same.

This is my `'DatabaseHelper'` any idea to solve the problem?

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(MusicInfoSQL.CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(PeopleInfoSQL.CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public Cursor getAllDataFromTable(String tableName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    if (tableName.equals(MusicInfoSQL.TABLE_NAME)
            || tableName.equals(PeopleInfoSQL.TABLE_NAME)) {
        return db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

This is the write method:

```
public boolean insertTrack(MusicInfoSQL music) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MusicInfoSQL.COLUMN_ID, music.getId());
    contentValues.put(MusicInfoSQL.COLUMN_NAME, music.getName());
    contentValues.put(MusicInfoSQL.COLUMN_AUTHOR, music.getAuthor());
    long result = db.insertWithOnConflict(MusicInfoSQL.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In any activity where I use **DB**:

```
DatabaseHelper mDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pls add your DatabaseHelper  class

Comment: @PraveenP I edit the question!

Comment: where is your db write code

Answer (score 0):

To avoid concurrency issues like that, you should open a database only once.

Use a **singleton pattern**.

See also [DataBaseHelper, Singleton or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564348/databasehelper-singleton-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

To avoid duplication of data 
use following code instead of 
    SQLiteDatabase db.insert(...)

```
 db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

put this in your write db code

**Update**

For example my write db code

```
  public void addInformations(SQLiteDatabase db, String id, String title, String cname, String image, String caddres, String clocation, String logo,String phone,String count, String valid) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(ProductEntry.ID, id);
    contentValues.put(ProductEntry.TITLE, title);
    contentValues.put(ProductEntry.NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(ProductEntry.IMAGE, image);

    db.insertWithOnConflict(ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

}
```

and  in your

```
 db.execSQL(MusicInfoSQL.CREATE_TABLE);
db.execSQL(PeopleInfoSQL.CREATE_TABLE);
```

set a primary key like this

```
   private static final String CREATE_TABLE= "create table " + ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" + ProductEntry.ID + " text PRIMARY KEY," ........
```

Comment: In insert query?

Comment: pls add your db write  method

Comment: I add the write method

Comment: did you set a primary key?